# React Native Hot Reload doesn't update the screen on changes?

Tags: javascript, react-native, hot-reload

I've recently started working in React Native. I was intrigued by the Hot and Live reload features. However, hot reload isn't working for exactly how it should (instant change). I understand the difference between Hot Reload and Live Reload.

The problem is, whenever I make a change in my file, say `profile.js`, there's a tooltip saying `Hot Reloading..`, but the changes I made are not reflected. Now to be clear, I am just changing the font size of a TextView, which is inside the render function. However, if I go to another activity and then come back to `profile.js`, it reflects the changes.

Is there something I am doing wrong, or is it a bug in the Hot Reload feature?

Any links to other places where I could find answers are totally welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Hot reload will not work for all the cases. When there is a change which needs the whole bundle to rebuild, in that case it wont work. Small changes like text change, or any other trivial changes which doesn't require to build whole project should work just fine. For validating if its working or not.

- Create a new project.
- Enable hot reload but disable the live reload.
- Change any text from the App.js file

Observe if there is any change in the screen or not. If it doesn't try upgrading the react native cli or reinstall.

Comment: "When there is a change which need the whole bundle to rebuild, in that case **it work**." --- this "is" a typing mistake right?

Comment: it didn't work. Tried all of the steps you mentioned.

Comment: Are you using React native or CRNA ?

Comment: Im using React native

Answer (score 2):

It consumes me up to 2 working days.
My app suddenly can't be hot reloaded.

I finally found the solution, the problem is with your watchman. So reinstall it:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman && brew uninstall watchman && brew install watchman
```